# Make & Make Install Errors on Alfa awus036h Driver Install

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, driver, linux-device-driver, make-install

I'm getting an error when trying to make && make install stock drivers for the Alfa awus036h wireless adapter.

**Make:**

```
me@me-myComputer-ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.o
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:153:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:155:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:168:12: error: ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:169:16: error: ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: In function ‘rtl8180_proc_module_init’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:427:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:427:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: In function ‘rtl8180_proc_init_one’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:461:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:479:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_read_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:479:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:489:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:518:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: At top level:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:3762:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:3862:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
me@me-myComputer-ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012$
```

**Make install:**

```
me@me-myComputer-ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for me: 
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko: kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/drivers/misc/eeprom/eeprom_93cx6.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko: kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko kernel/drivers/misc/eeprom/eeprom_93cx6.ko
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187'
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/build M=/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187 CC=gcc modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.o
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:153:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:155:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:168:12: error: ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:169:16: error: ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: In function ‘rtl8180_proc_module_init’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:427:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:427:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: In function ‘rtl8180_proc_init_one’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:461:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:479:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_read_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:479:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:489:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:518:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c: At top level:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:3762:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:3862:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_disconnect’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187'
make: *** [install] Error 2
me@me-myComputer-ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012$
```

I'm trying to update the driver to include a non-IEEE frequency (2.420 GHz) that's within range of the hardware, but the drivers didn't compile prior making any changes either.

Ubuntu 12.04

Driver: RTL8187, installed per instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/178009/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-alfa-awus036h-usb-wireless-adapter

Comment: did you get any solution mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the driver just wasn't compatible. Obviously not the answer I hoped for at the time, but think I had to go with different hardware to suit the purpose.